# Invalid number SQL error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a statement like this. While I can execute this statement in Oracle 11g and see the results. However my friend (he also uses Oracle 11g) can not execute this statement. He gets invalid number error. I can not understand why. Could you help me? He also tried casting upper_threshold as varchar but it did not work.

```
select *
from table
where (lower_threshold <> to_char( 0) or upper_threshold = 0 or upper_threshold is null)
```

lower_threshold has varchar type, upper threshold is integer value.

Comment: `lower_threshold <> '0'` (but I why on earth is `lower_threshold` a `varchar` is `upper_threshold` is an integer?)

Comment: i do not know i do not have the table :)

Comment: Try `upper_threshold = '0'` - does that work for both of you?

Comment: unfortunately no :( he cant execute this one but i can execute it . It is confusing

Comment: You can try to narrow down the problem. What happens if you try `select lower_threshold from table where lower_threshold <> '0'`? What about `select upper_threshold from table where upper_threshold = '0'`? Which column is giving you trouble? It's really odd that you would get the INVALID NUMBER error (specifically that one) if you change `0` to `'0'`, since there aren't ANY numbers left in the query.

Comment: One thing to check is certainly the data type of the columns. You do that with `describe my_table` (where `my_table` is the name of your table). Note that this is not a SQL statement, it is a SQL\*Plus command (understood by Toad and SQL Developer etc.); you don't need to terminate it with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle hurls `ORA-01722: invalid number` when we attempt to cast a non-numeric value to a number datatype.

You say "upper threshold is integer value" but it seems more likely that datatype of `table.upper_threshold` is a string datatype (VARCHAR2 or similar),  like `table.lower_threshold` . In such a situation, when you execute a filter like this:

```
upper_threshold = 0
```

what Oracle implements is this

```
to_number(upper_threshold) = 0
```

You do not get the ORA-01722 error because all of the values in your table will convert happily to numbers. Your friend is not so lucky, and he has non-numeric values in the `upper_threshold` column (spaces, letters, whatever).

The teaching is, always use NUMBER columns to store numbers.

---

> "Actually, we both connect to the same database, same tables"

Basically the thing is, if two people run the same SQL against the same actual table with the same data they will get the same outcome. So one of you must be doing something different from the other. Possibly it's a problem with client settings, although I can't think of an environment parameter which might cause an ORA-01722 error. Much more likely is that one of you is running a different statement or using a different table or (as Mathguy suggests) running against a different data set.

Comment: Actually, we both connect to the same database, same tables.  The point that I do not understand is that why I can execute the statement, while he can't. How could it be ?  We both have only select grants. Then he cast the upper threshold value to number , used replaced function to remove spaces but it does not work.

Comment: @asdfg - That may happen for a variety of reasons... for example, one of you has uncommitted changes to the table. The one who made the changes but did not commit them can see the modified table, the other one can only see the "older" state of the same table.

Comment: If `upper_threshold` is an integer columns why would you try "replaced function to remove spaces "? Spaces are not numeric, so an integer cannot have spaces.

Comment: We both connect to the same database, same tables,same  queries

Comment: Then it's a mystery. There's no way we can diagnose paranormal activity in your environment remotely​.